# Google Maps API Distance Calculation

Tags: google-maps

In Google maps api I am writing a calculation script for a taxi company.

The charge per mile, which I have done. However, if the destination is within the Greater London area, the price goes up from £1.50 to £2.50 per mile.

Does anyone know how to calculate the distance travelled within this area?

I understand I can define the area as a polygon, but I don't know how to calculate the distance traveled in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Could you calculate the distance of the polyline, using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698112/how-to-add-markers-on-google-maps-polylines-based-on-distance-along-the-line), and then determine whether the polyline passes through your polygon - using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385523/does-this-polyline-pass-through-this-polygon) - and at what points/distance it crosses, to then determine how much to charge.

Answer (score 0):

with locatio class there is method that give you the distance between two geo point. location.distance(location2)